# Ideas to divided bandwidth to clients in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, devops

How to separate bandwidth to clients in SaaS plaform?
Example: wix separate in GB to each client type.
I use Laravel in Google compute engine, but any tip is valid

Comment: Why do you need this? The current GCP bandwidth is not enough?

Comment: I want only separate bandwidth to each client. Example: He pay a plan of 2GB bandwith so he should have only 2GB of bandwidth. My site will be like wix.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do this with Google Cloud product. Maybe you need to install a third party tool for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe If we talking about SaaS your have to find your solution from third-party tools since GCP mostly is a Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) or Platform as a Service (PaaS).

Please take look at following document which outline Rate-limiting strategies and techniques in GCP

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/rate-limiting-strategies-techniques
and
https://stripe.com/blog/rate-limiters